# Importing google chrome files

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed windows 10 but unfortuantely, I didn't sync my google accounts. but I have still the old windows folder with the cache and everything. is there a way to restore those bookmarks, history into windows 10 current chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Default\Default\` folder on your computer. This is where you'll be copying the `Bookmarks` and `History` files into. Now locate that same folder location in your old Windows folder and grab the `Bookmarks` and `History` files and copy & replace them into `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Default\Default\`